# SQL join with linker table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables in my database for a quiz application:

```
Quiz
- QuizID
- QuizName

QuizQuestions
- QuizQuestionID
- Text

LNK_Quiz_QuizQuestion
- ID
- QuizID
- QuizQuestionID
```

I use a linker table so that quiz questions can belong to more than one quiz.

To pull a list of questions for a quiz, I am doing the following:

```
"SELECT * FROM QuizQuestions
 INNER JOIN LNK_Quiz_QuizQuestion
 ON QuizQuestions.QuizQuestionID = LNK_Quiz_QuizQuestion.QuizID
 WHERE QuizID = '" + id + "'"
```

But I'm confused about what JOINS to use to link the three tables to pull the data I want out.

Comment: It depend on your data and usage. Most propery it's an INNER JOIN you need.  http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the link table is an intersection table between your two tables, you should join on both columns:

```
 SELECT qq.Text FROM QuizQuestions qq
 INNER JOIN LNK_Quiz_QuizQuestion lqq ON qq.QuizQuestionID = lqq.QuizQuestionID 
 INNER JOIN Quiz q ON lqq.QuizID = q.QuizID
 WHERE q.QuizID = ?
```